Is the high initial rate of expansion shown in most images of an expanding universe, due to inflation?
Most images of an expanding universe look something like this. Inflation itself is far too short-lived to show up on an image showing the entire lifetime of the universe, but is the rapid initial rate of expansion a consequence of inflation?
As I understand, the Lambda CDM model can be run with or without inflation. If it is run without inflation do we still see these high initial rates of expansion?
     The expanding universe

Related question on inflation in $\Lambda$CDM
